# EhCache Exception

Tags: ehcache, searchable

I am getting the below exception while using searchable with `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0`

> net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Search attributes
>   not supported by this store type: net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore

Can Somebody help!

Comment: Can you please add your Ehcache configuration to the question?

Comment: @LouisJacomet This is resolved Thank you.